# Error using `\ifthenelse` from `xifthen` in theorem optional arg, with package `thm-restate` loaded

Tags: thmtools, ifthenelse, xifthen

I want to put a conditional of the form `\ifthenelse{\isempty{…}}{…}{…}` in the optional argument of an `amsthm`-style theorem.  Ordinarily, this works fine, but the package `thm-restate` (from `thmtools`) seems to break it.

I’ve tried adding brackets, adding `\protect` in various places, and so on, but can’t find a way to make this work.  Can anyone suggest a way to get around this?  A MWE is the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[\ifthenelse{\isempty{foo}}{bar}{baz}]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This gives `Undefined control sequence.` on the `\isempty` (and several further errors).  It compiles fine when `thm-restate` is removed.

Replacing `\isempty` with the other conditional commands of `xifthen` (like `\isin`, `\isequal` and so on) gives similar errors.

The above example minimally illustrates the error.  However, my actual use-case has an extra complication which may be relevant: it’s wrapped into another environment, which passes an argument in to `\isempty`.  It’s something like the following (which can be appended to the earlier MWE):

```latex
\newenvironment{mytheorem}[1][]
  {\begin{theorem}[Note\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{~arg: #1}]}
  {\end{theorem}}

\begin{mytheorem}[foo]
  Theorem text.
\end{mytheorem}
```

So I am really hoping for a solution which works with this not-quite-minimal example also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an expandable test:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\tlifempty \tl_if_empty:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[\tlifempty{foo}{bar}{baz}]
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}[\tlifempty{}{bar}{baz}]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou!  Just a note: to make this compile, I need to add the `xparse` package; otherwise I get `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.` at `\ExplSyntaxOn`.  Is that the right way to make `\ExplSyntaxOn` etc available, or is there a more canonical way?

Comment: In a current tex system expl3 is loaded by latex, but if your system is older you should load xparse or expl3 in your document.

Comment: thanks!  Loading it automatically must be pretty recent though: I’m on TexLive 2019, so not much out-of-date.

Comment: it is recent, but a final texlive 2019 should have it too.